# setOnItemClickListener no se ejecuta en el fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, customadapter

Estoy usando un GridView dentro de un RelativeLayout que contiene una imagen, un checkbox y un textview. Uso un adapter para seleccionar o deseleccionar los checkbox. Uso un fragment para mostrar el GridView. El checkbox se selecciona/deselecciona tocándolo o tocando la imagen. Tengo implementado el *onClick* del checkbox y del imageview.

En el Fragment, intento conocer los elementos seleccionados para habilitar/inhabilitar un menú del propio fragment pero el problema está en que el método **setOnItemClickListener** no se está ejecutando.

Ante todo, quiero decir que ya consulté las respuestas a preguntas similares a esta y he aplicado cada una pero no funciona, por lo que debo "repetirla".

Tengo el código para ello de la siguiente manera:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_residuos, container, false);
    final GridView gridview = view.findViewById(R.id.grid_elements);
    adapter = new ResiduosAdapter(this.activity);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    // creo un objeto listener
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Click ListItem Number " + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    };
    // asigno el objeto listener al gridview
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
    return view;
}
```

En muchas de las respuestas mencionan el poner `android:focusable="false"` en cada elemento, lo cual ya hice pero sigue sin funcionar.

El Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    p1:padding="10dp">

    <GridView
        p1:id="@+id/grid_elements"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        p1:clickable="false"
        p1:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        p1:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:numColumns="3"
        p1:verticalSpacing="2dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

El custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:background="@color/primary_material_light"
    p1:focusable="false"
    p1:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:minWidth="25px">

    <ImageView
        p1:id="@+id/elements_img"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        p1:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        p1:focusable="false"
        p1:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        p1:src="@drawable/envases_plasticos" />

    <TextView
        p1:id="@+id/elements_name"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_below="@+id/elements_img"
        p1:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        p1:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        p1:focusable="false"
        p1:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        p1:text="     "
        p1:textColor="@color/primary_dark_material_dark"
        p1:textSize="@dimen/abc_edit_text_inset_top_material" />

    <CheckBox
        p1:id="@+id/elements_check"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_alignRight="@id/elements_img"
        p1:focusable="false"
        p1:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

No funciona por que deberias implementar una interfaz para poder hacer un `onClickListener` en los elementos del `gridView`, a diferencia de button, estas haciendo click en vistas que se inflan, por lo tanto deberias implementar la parte del `onClick` en el adaptador del gridView, otra cosa que te sugeriria, es usar un `RecyclerView` con un `GridLayoutManager`, ya que vas a poder tener una mayor performance en tu app.

Para eso usa `setOnClickListener()` dentro de tu adaptador

Podes seguir este video para implementar el `GridLayoutManager`  en el video usa `LinearLayoutManager`, pero solamente lo cambias por el grid y listo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHdTs_-PrYA&t

Comment: Perdón, omití esa parte del código. Ya he implementado el onClickListener para los elementos del gridView, no tengo problema en ello, el problema es que desde el adapter no puedo habilitar/inhabilitar un menú del fragment que es lo que estoy intentando con el setOnItemClickListener (a menos que haya un modo de hacerlo, y posiblemente esto cambie el contexto de la pregunta).

Answer (score 0):

No ser si lo entiendo quieres que des de el framgment/activity puedas interceptar el `Onclick` de cada elemento del grid?

Buscando por la red [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-implement-onClick-event-in-activity-class-in-Recyclerview-in-android) he encontrado lo siguiente, prueba si es lo que necesitas

```
public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(ContentItem item);
}

private final List<ContentItem> items;
private final OnItemClickListener listener;

public ContentAdapter(List<ContentItem> items, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.items = items;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
}

@Override public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView name;
    private ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }

    public void bind(final ContentItem item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        name.setText(item.name);
        Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(item.imageUrl).into(image);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick(item);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Luego para interceptar el `OnItemClilckListener()` desde el adaptador.

```
recycler.setAdapter(new ContentAdapter(items, new ContentAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override public void onItemClick(ContentItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}));
```

Comment: El ejemplo lo obtuve de http://www.androhub.com/android-listview-checkbox/ y lo curioso es que de acuerdo al autor, el setOnClickListener debería funcionar pero no.